# Can AD Membership Provider be configured to use Kerberos

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-membership

I have a web app that uses the Active Directory Membership Provider and when 
a user changes their password, they can login with either the old password or 
the new password for a while.

This KB article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906305/en-us) leads me to 
believe that this behavior is caused by NTLM authentication.

Is there a way to configure the AD Membership Provider to only do Kerberos 
Authentication and not NTLM?

NOTE: My app configures the provider with a minimum set of parameters, so every 
configuration setting is set to its default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that you can change the method used. Its odd that both passwords would still work unless the credentials are being cached locally as if it were a disconnected machine (similar to what happens when you disconnect a machine from a domain and log into it). This doesnt sound like something the provider itself is doing, unless the provider is caching credentials. I didnt see anything for expiration of credentials which leads me to believe that it is not doing that.

Is sounds odd that they could log in with **both** passwords, I would expect one or the other to work, depending on GC replication lag between DCs or something along that lines.

Comment: I believe from the KB article mentioned that this behavior is on the domain controller and has nothing to do with IIS/ASP.Net or the AD membership provider.  But this behavior applies to NTLM authentication and not to Kerberos.  So that is why I want the AD membership provider to use Kerberos.